# Erro na divisão do contador

Tags: c, loop, matemática

Por que o meu código está realizando a divisão da média errada por causa da variável `contador`?

```
int numero,contador, soma;
float media;

soma = 0;

for (contador = 1; contador <= 3; contador++) {
    printf("Digite um numero inteiro : ");
    scanf("%d",&numero);
    soma = soma + numero;   
}

media = (float)soma / contador;

printf("A media dos numeros e %.2f \n",media);
```

Comment: Da maneira como você fez o valor da variável `contador` é o valor com que saiu do loop `for` ou seja: 4 (o for parte de 1 e vai incrementando 1 enquanto for <= 3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porque você começou a contagem no 1, em geral sempre começamos no 0, isso funciona melhor para acessar dados em um *array* e para fazer contagens como esta. Começando do 0 e terminando quando for igual ao número que deseja que pare você deixa o código mais legível e usará o valor certo para fazer a divisão da média. Então nesse caso quando chega a 3 ele encerra e não repete mais, ele faz pedido de entrada de dados com o contador valendo 0, 1 e 2, mas com 3 ele encerra e não faz. E foi exatamente 3 dados entrados, portanto a divisão fica ok.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int soma = 0;
    int contador = 0;
    for (; contador < 3; contador++) {
        printf("Digite um numero inteiro : ");
        int numero;
        scanf("%d", &numero);
        soma += numero;   
    }
    printf("A media dos numeros e %.2f \n", (float)soma / contador);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/FTsBw0). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/LoopIndexc). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/LoopIndex.c).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua explicação, conseguir entender aonde eu estava errando.